# Does disorientating the hostage do anything?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

I noticed as Echo if you use your Yokai to disorientate the hostage you get -5 points. Does anything actually bad happen to the hostage when you do that or does the game subtract 5 points for nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, besides losing points for spooking the hostage, it has no effect gameplay-wise.  Attackers can still rescue the hostage even if the hostage has been recently disoriented.